# Revision history message for answer-to-comment conversion is inconsistently phrased

Tags: bug, revisions-list, convert-to-comment

A very minor issue, but (even though [Mana](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/207/mana) totally [didn't do anything](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=7538630#7538630)) as you can see in [the revision history for a particular Arqade answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/98520/revisions), the phrasing used to describe the conversion to comment event is inconsistent with the "<descriptor> <past-tense-action> <by?>"-ish language used for other events:

[image: inconsistently phrased revision entries]

I would expect the text to read something like "Post converted to comment by moderator" instead.

[Grace Note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note) [noted in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=7538760#7538760) that the wording is closer to that used in some other (presumably moderator) interface, and that the applicable text there isn't as expected either, so perhaps the relevant descriptions have just been swapped or something.