# Comment conversion hides converter from OP, but not from others

Tags: discussion, bug, convert-to-comment, trusted-user

When a moderator [converts an answer to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74160/153355), the original poster gets told to see the FAQ for why.

For example, from [this ELU question’s](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14334/2085) [(now-deleted) answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/14336/2085), which got converted to [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14334/what-does-the-term-86d-relate-to/14336#comment206466_14334), this is the OP’s view of his deleted answer:

[image: Rob’s view of deleted posting]

However, the rest of us 10k users can see just fine what happened, as could Rob if he looked in the recently deleted queue quickly enough:

[image: Others’ view of deleted posting]

Isn’t this a bug that anybody **save** the OP gets to see which moderator did the conversion? Why can’t the OP see this?

I mean hey, at nearly 80,000 rep, you’d think Rob has earned that privilege, you know?  He shouldn’t have to run to other 10k users to see what they can see.  Isn’t 80k trusted enough yet?

<sub>(There is something reduplicatively ironic in the answer to Rob’s “Why?” question being *waiwai*.)</sub>

Comment: I'd also make it obvious to 10k users that the post was converted to a comment instead of showing that it was "merely" deleted.

Comment: Related: [Show all users if a post was converted to a comment, instead of just the owner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113386)

Comment: Hmm, I guess this makes the fact that the moderator name isn't shown in the [converted-to-comment revision entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161750/revision-history-message-for-answer-to-comment-conversion-is-inconsistently-phra) a bit silly too.